# RDOMail UserProperties not being created

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I am using Redemption to create some UserProperties on a list of Email Objects, and I have these four lines in an Outlook 2013 Add-In:

```
RDOMail rdoMail = Globals.ThisAddIn.session.GetMessageFromID(folder.Items[1].EntryID);
RDOUserProperty rdoUP = rdoMail.UserProperties.Add("PropertyName", rdoUserPropertyType.olText, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
rdoUP.Value = "value";
rdoMail.Save();
```

But there are no UserProperties created.

Anybody knows why?

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the properties on the right item? folder.Items[1] will *not* return the very first message that you are seeing in Outlook Explorer.

Comment: Yes, it will return the very first message. In fact, there is a variable "i" to get all the Items in the folder. I have tried everything but the properties are not set somehow.

Comment: Ho do you check that the properties are not set? Did you look at the messages with OutlookSpy (click IMessage button)?

Comment: I look at the _User Defined Fields_ in the Columns of the Mail List, they usually appear there, but not this time.

Comment: Yes, it is there using OutlookSpy, thanks!

Comment: These are two different things - in general, UserProperties are only defined on the item level. That is unless AddToFolderFields parameter is true when you are calling UserProperties.Add. Folder fields are accessible through MAPIFolder.UserDefinedProperties in OOM or RDOFolder.FolderFields in Redemption. Folder fields only contain the property definitions, but the actual values are stored on the items.

Comment: I have another problem now. The UserProperties are created but I have to close and reopen Outlook in order to see the new UserProperties. Do you have any idea why and how to solve this?

Comment: See the answer below (it is too long for a comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook cannot see changes made with MAPI - you will have the same problem even if you do not use Redemption: if you connect to the same Exchange mailbox from two machines, changes made on one machine will not be visible on another machine until the item in question is completely dereferenced and reopened.

The rule of thumb is to either avoid opening the item using OOM or (if you absolutely have to) release it as soon as you are done using Marshal.ReleaseComObject. You also need to be careful to avoid multiple dot notation to make sure no implicit variables (which you cannot reference) are create by the compiler.

Comment: OK, and what should I release  in this case. I have tried releasing the rdoUserProperties, the rdoMail and nothing, I still have to restart Outlook.

Comment: And the most strange part is why it was working yesterday and not today? Even my GF is more stable than that!

Comment: Does this only happen for the item currently selected in Outlook or for all items in the folder? What is your actual code that open the items using OOM? In your code above, instead of touching all items with OOM< and using GetMessageFromID, why not open the folder RDOSession.GetFolderFromID? This way you would not need to use OOM to touch each and every item.

Comment: A call to `GC.Collect()` did the magic, as you said they had to be released using `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`, then surely they were released but not garbage collected, so this line makes it work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Marshal.ReleaseComObject should be enough. If you need to call GC.Collect(), this is an indication that either you are not releasing all COM objects using Marshal.ReleaseComObject, or that you have implicit variables due to multiple dot notation (e.g. rdoUP = rdoMail.UserProperties.Add will create an implicit variable to hold the value of the rdoMail.UserProperties property).